# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "spirit_category_category_pkey"

Tags: python, django, postgresql

## The Error

I'm using django and [spirit](https://github.com/nitely/Spirit) to build a website. In a test, when I was inserting new data into a table called `spirit_category_category`, I got the following error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "spirit_category_category_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

Note that there were already two other records in the table with ids of `1` and `2`. So inserting `Key(id)=(1)` wouldn't work, of course. But the sql executed didn't include `id` field. That is, `Key (id)=(1)` was automatically generated by postgresql, why did it generate an already existed id?

## The Reason

To find out the reason, I ran the following command in postgresql:

```
test_spiritdb=# select start_value, last_value, max_value from spirit_category_category_id_seq;
 start_value | last_value |      max_value      
-------------+------------+---------------------
           1 |          1 | 9223372036854775807
(1 row)
```

So basically, `last_value` is `1`, so postgresql will generate `Key (id)=(1)` every time, I tried to alter it to 3, and everything is fine.

```
test_spiritdb=# alter sequence spirit_category_category_id_seq restart with 3;
```

## I don't know how to fix it for a test

The test passed. But it is a test, so it is meaningless to alter a test table because the test database will be deleted and created again for every test, so the next time the test will fail again because `last_value` will still be generated as `1`. So I wondered why django/postgresql would generate such an abnormal value for `last_value`? How to fix it? The models and migrations for `category` are as follows, if it helps.

## models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import settings

from .managers import CategoryQuerySet
from ..core.utils.models import AutoSlugField

class Category(models.Model):

    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', verbose_name=_("category parent"), null=True, blank=True)

    title = models.CharField(_("title"), max_length=75)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from="title", db_index=False, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(_("description"), max_length=255, blank=True)
    is_global = models.BooleanField(_("global"), default=True,
                                    help_text=_('Designates whether the topics will be'
                                                'displayed in the all-categories list.'))
    is_closed = models.BooleanField(_("closed"), default=False)
    is_removed = models.BooleanField(_("removed"), default=False)
    is_private = models.BooleanField(_("private"), default=False)

    # topic_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("topic count"), default=0)

    objects = CategoryQuerySet.as_manager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title', 'pk']
        verbose_name = _("category")
        verbose_name_plural = _("categories")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        if self.pk == settings.ST_TOPIC_PRIVATE_CATEGORY_PK:
            return reverse('spirit:topic:private:index')
        else:
            return reverse('spirit:category:detail', kwargs={'pk': str(self.id), 'slug': self.slug})

    @property
    def is_subcategory(self):
        if self.parent_id:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

## 0001_initial.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations
import spirit.core.utils.models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Category',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='ID', serialize=True, auto_created=True)),
                ('title', models.CharField(verbose_name='title', max_length=75)),
                ('slug', spirit.core.utils.models.AutoSlugField(db_index=False, populate_from='title', blank=True)),
                ('description', models.CharField(verbose_name='description', max_length=255, blank=True)),
                ('is_closed', models.BooleanField(verbose_name='closed', default=False)),
                ('is_removed', models.BooleanField(verbose_name='removed', default=False)),
                ('is_private', models.BooleanField(verbose_name='private', default=False)),
                ('parent', models.ForeignKey(null=True, verbose_name='category parent', to='spirit_category.Category', blank=True)),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ['title', 'pk'],
                'verbose_name': 'category',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'categories',
            },
        ),
    ]
```

## 0002_auto_20150728_0442.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations
from django.conf import settings


def default_categories(apps, schema_editor):
    Category = apps.get_model("spirit_category", "Category")

    if not Category.objects.filter(pk=settings.ST_TOPIC_PRIVATE_CATEGORY_PK).exists():
        Category.objects.create(
            pk=settings.ST_TOPIC_PRIVATE_CATEGORY_PK,
            title="Private",
            slug="private",
            is_private=True
        )

    if not Category.objects.filter(pk=settings.ST_UNCATEGORIZED_CATEGORY_PK).exists():
        Category.objects.create(
            pk=settings.ST_UNCATEGORIZED_CATEGORY_PK,
            title="Uncategorized",
            slug="uncategorized"
        )


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('spirit_category', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(default_categories),
    ]
```

## 0003_category_is_global.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('spirit_category', '0002_auto_20150728_0442'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='category',
            name='is_global',
            field=models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Designates whether the topics will bedisplayed in the all-categories list.', verbose_name='global'),
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After lots of debugging, I finally found the solution. The reason is that I was trying to insert two another `categories` with specified **id**s, which would cause postgresql stop increasing the `last_value` of the relative `sequence`. Just as follows:

## 0002_auto_20150728_0442.py

```
if not Category.objects.filter(pk=settings.ST_TOPIC_PRIVATE_CATEGORY_PK).exists():
    Category.objects.create(
        pk=settings.ST_TOPIC_PRIVATE_CATEGORY_PK,
        title="Private",
        slug="private",
        is_private=True
    )

if not Category.objects.filter(pk=settings.ST_UNCATEGORIZED_CATEGORY_PK).exists():
    Category.objects.create(
        pk=settings.ST_UNCATEGORIZED_CATEGORY_PK,
        title="Uncategorized",
        slug="uncategorized"
    )
```

The way to fix this is simple, either change the `last_value` manually in `django`, or just don't specify the id, i.e. remove the following lines:

```
....
pk=settings.ST_TOPIC_PRIVATE_CATEGORY_PK,
....
pk=settings.ST_UNCATEGORIZED_CATEGORY_PK,
....
```

I guess if you let django undertake the task of managing `id`, it may not be a good idea to specify the `id` yourself when inserting new data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue is with your migrations.

You're trying to add multiple identical `spirit_category_category` objects which will trigger the same auto-incremented `id` if not configured correctly in the Django test suite. One option would be to identify the conflicting tests and move them into separate `TestCase` classes (because `setUp` will flush your database for you).

Another option would be to use a library like [Factory Boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to create your model instances which will help avoid conflicts like this.

Comment: I was inserting the same `id` into the table, just as you say. I removed the `id` part and everything was fine again. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I needed to keep the ID as I am restoring data from another server and have keep the relationships, etc.
My solution was to add another command on the migrations file to run after inserting the items and reset the database sequence for the involved tables.

To get the command to reset the table sequence you could run `python manage.py sqlsequencereset spirit` as documented on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#sqlsequencereset

Then on your migration `0002_auto_20150728_0442.py` file add:

```
from django.db connection

def reset_spirit_pk_sequence(apps, schema_editor):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("RESULT_FROM_SQLRESETSEQUENCE")
    row = cursor.fetchone()

...
...

operations = [
    migrations.RunPython(default_categories),
    migrations.RunPython(reset_spirit_pk_sequence),
]
```

Note to replace `RESULT_FROM_SQLRESETSEQUENCE` with the line of command you got from the `manage.py sqlresetsequence` related to the table you are having problems(escaping inner `"` with `\`).

Answer (score 0):

In a test, my code was trying to save a row without passing id (primary key), yet I was getting:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint ...
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

I worked around the problem as follows:

```
iOneMore = Model.objects.last().id + 1
oNew = Model( id = iOneMore, col1 = string1, col2 = string2 )
oNew.save()
```

Problem solved, no more error.